# Shapefiles being saved to my documents folder

Tags: qgis, shapefile

Apparently, after a recent upgrade to windows 10, QGIS started to save new shape files to my documents folder ignoring my project folder. I reinstalled/updated QGIS 3.12.3 and problem remained. Are there Windows/QGIS environmental settings that have changed?

Comment: What do you mean by saving ShapeFiles? You choose where the output goes when you run any tool.